# Counting characters before a ',' in each index of array, and returning the highest

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, substring, names

I need to get the longest surname from this array and return it.

```
String[] names = {"Turner, Brendan", "Savage, Fred", "Zidy, Boop",
                 "Zobie, Brendan", "Flurb, Fred", "Mopeeeeeyyy, Boopertinson"};
```

So far I have this;

```
public static void getLongestSurname(String[] name){
         int i = 0;
         int x = 0;
         int currentLength = 0; 
         int lastLength = 0; 
         String longestName = null;
    for(int j = 0; j < (name.length); j++){
      
          while (name[j].charAt(i) != ',') {
          i++;
          currentLength++;
          }
      System.out.println(i);
      System.out.println("current is"+currentLength);
      i = 0;
      currentLength = 0;
        if ( currentLength > lastLength ){
           longestName = name[i]; 
          }
    }
    
     System.out.println("longest surname should be; "+ longestName);
  }
```

but the output it gives is "longest surname should be; Turner, Brendan"
which isn't the longest name in the list.

I'm doing something wrong here, but my brain feels like scrambled egg at this point. Can anyone help?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the `longestName` while iterating all names, compare the length of current name with length of current `longestString` instead of comparing with lastLength

longestName will be updated if length of currentName is greater than length of longestNumber

**Solution**

```
public static void getLongestSurname(String[] name){
        
        int currentLength = 0; 
        int lastLength = 0; 
        String longestName = null;
        for(int j = 0; j < (name.length); j++){

           // split string by "," to get surname
            String[] strAr = name[j].split(",");
            // length of current surname 
            currentLength = strAr[0].length();
           // compare length of current surname with longest surName                
            if ( currentLength > lastLength ){
                longestName = name[j]; 
                lastLength = strAr[0].length();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("longest surname should be; "+ longestName);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you here. But as I'm using it here longestname is just going to be the filtered down surname for whatever's in name[i].

At the point of the if statement, it's null. And of course if my array just contained surnames, I could use the .length operator since the string in that index array and the surname are the same number, but with these strings, there's a ", firstname" on the end I need to ignore in my comparison. 

Hopefully this at least gives you an idea about the nature of my confusion. Thank you for your suggestion, sorry I'm not following.

Answer (score 0):

For each name in the array, parse the surname.  Compare that against the current longest surname.  If the current is null or shorter then replace it.   Keep doing this until the list is exhausted.  Return the result.

```
public String findLongestSurname(String[] names) {
  String longestSurname = null;
  for (String name : names) {
    String[] tokens = name.split(",");
    String surname = tokens[0];
    if (longestSurname == null || surname.length > longestSurname.length) {
      longestSurname = surname;
    }
  }
  return longestSurname;
}
```